# Calling Meteor server side methods from public js asset

Tags: meteor

What is the approach for doing a Meteor.call to the server from a js file within the /public folder?

I tested, but the call does not work. I am unable to get any result from Meteor.call when using it within the js filed that is served on the public...

Will I need to create a middleware api ?

Answer (score 1):

Why is the JS file in the public directory? If you want the JS code to be executed on the client, then put it in the /client directory and the functions will be available to the client.

If it's in the public folder, then it is served "as-is" to the client. From the docs:

> public
>
> All files inside a top-level directory called public/ are served as-is to the client. When referencing these assets, do not include public/ in the URL, write the URL as if they were all in the top level. For example, reference public/bg.png as . This is the best place for favicon.ico, robots.txt, and similar files

**UPDATE**
Since now I can see you are trying to load an external JS, the correct answer is to either use NPM (with meteor 1.3+) or place them in the client/compatibility directory. From the docs (http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html):

> client/compatibility
>
> This folder is for compatibility with JavaScript libraries that rely on variables declared with var at the top level being exported as globals. Files in this directory are executed without being wrapped in a new variable scope. These files are executed before other client-side JavaScript files.
>
> It is recommended to use npm for 3rd party JavaScript libraries and use import to control when files are loaded.

Comment: I am using a package that contains many JS files that I was having issues getting them to serve when I wrapped them into the regular /client directory. But I can try getting them to work.

Comment: Thanks for updated answer, i will try to place them inside 'client/compatibility' folder. That could possibly be a great option for this situation.